# Java 8 Graphics2D, Freehand Drawing as mouse is dragged using Point (E.G Point pointStart)

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am using `Graphics2D`, `Point`, and `Line2D` (For BrushStroke) to create a free hand drawing program (for educational purposes). My problem is, that I can get the line to draw using mouse drag, but it keeps originating from top left corner of `JPanel` to where I release the mouse button. I would like to be able to use `Point` (E.G Point startPoint, endPoint) to be able to draw as mouse is being moved, stop when released, and begin drawing at new point when mouse is pressed again. Can someone help me with the coding withing the mouse listeners (mousedragged, ...pressed, ...released, etc)?

```
    public class GraphicsPanel extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

private Color color;
private JColorChooser cc;
private JComboBox paintToolBox;

Point pointStart = null;
Point pointEnd = null;

GraphicsPanel(JColorChooser cc, Color color, JComboBox paintToolBox) {
    this.cc = cc;
    this.color = color;
    this.paintToolBox = paintToolBox;
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(cc.getColor());
    Line2D line2D = new Line2D.Double(pointStart, pointEnd);

    if (pointStart != null || pointEnd != null) {
        g2d.draw(line2D);
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

}
```

}

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for working examples of the two common ways to do this type of drawing. The examples draw a Rectangle, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Thank you, will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- First always override paintComponent, not paint
- And always call the super's painting method within your override
- You have two options here:

  1. Option 1:

     - Create an `ArrayList<Line2D>` as an instance field
     - Create lines and place into this list within your mouse/mousemotion listeners
     - then call repaint and iterate through this list within the paintComponent method, drawing lines
  2. Option 2:

     - Create a BufferedImage as an instance field
     - In your mouse/mousemotion listeners draw onto this image
     - then draw the image within your paintComponent method.
- Either way, the new line starts in mousePressed and is complete in mouseReleased

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to use Line2D in the ArrayList instance, I tried using ArrayList<Point> but didn't quite produce the results I was looking for. Thank you! I will try that!